# razor display image using base64 string

Tags: html, razor

i' have a well formatted base64 string which i'm displaying as follow :

and its been converted to data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIsAAAApCAYAAAAFzdoaAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAF8mlUWHRYTUw6Y29tLmFkb2JlLnhtcAAAAAAAPD94cG...�������������

note that i tried to remove the multi lines in the base64 using the following regex :

`Regex.Replace(content, @"\s+", string.Empty)`

also the charset in my html is :`<meta charset="utf-8" />`

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To display Base64 image in html you can do this:

```
<div>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIsAAAApCAYAAAAFzdoaAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAF8mlUWHRYTUw6Y29tLmFkb2JlLnhtcAAAAAAAPD94cG" />
</div>
```

If you need any other help please describe your problem in detail.